# jQuery animate only one item (div) on hover (img)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

The situation is to make jQuery animating only one element when another one is hovered. Now I get all the items animating when hover action begins.

Code:

```
<table width="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;" width="390" height="246">
            <div class="album-back"></div>
            <img id="album_action" src="../upload/img/album1.jpg" width="285" height="246" />
        </td>
        <td width="240">
            Description
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;" width="390" height="246">
            <div class="album-back"></div>
            <img id="album_action" src="../upload/img/album2.jpg" width="285" height="246" />
        </td>
        <td width="240">
            Description
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#album_action").hover(function(){
        $('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 400);
    }, function(){
        $('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
    });
});
```

When I hover img with id "#album_action", i get an ".album-back" div moving. But animation starts for all ".album-back" div elemens on page. How can I get animating only one element without entering different classes and ids? Maybe there's some way to set class for  and to set actions inside only current active (hovered) ?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is called invalid html if you use same ids for multiple elements in a single page.

Comment: Thanks, Jai. I've really missed it. And thank you very much - to everyone, who answered my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you gave one id twice. ID shall be unique, therefore only appear for ONE element.

Rather use .album_action than #album_action.

Second, why are using a table? You dont do that since the 80s anymore :)

If the .action and the .back are on the same level, you can use jQuery siblings

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".album_action").hover(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 400);
    }, function(){
        $(this).siblings('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` should be unique, you need to use `class` instead:

```
<img class="album_action" src="../upload/img/album2.jpg" width="285" height="246" />
```

Then you can use `$(this)` to target current element:

```
$(".album_action").hover(function(){
    $(this).prev('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 400);
}, function(){
    $(this).prev('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eli! It works exactly as I wanted. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<table width="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;" width="390" height="246">
            <div class="album-back"></div>
            <img class="album_action" src="../upload/img/album1.jpg" width="285" height="246" />
        </td>
        <td width="240">
            Description
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;" width="390" height="246">
            <div class="album-back"></div>
            <img class="album_action" src="../upload/img/album2.jpg" width="285" height="246" />
        </td>
        <td width="240">
            Description
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In **HTML** there is only one change that `img id` is replaced by `img class`
as `is` must be `unique`.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".album_action").hover(function(){
        $('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
        $(this).prev('div.album-back').animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 400);
    }, function(){
        $(this).prev('div.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the `id` to `class` because same ids for multiple elements in a single page is called invalid html.

Try changing id to class:

```
$(".album_action").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '150px'}, 400);
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings('.album-back').stop().animate({'margin-left': '100px'}, 250);
});
```

you can use `.siblings()` to find at same level of the hovered element.